# Convert vector<wchar_t> to string c++

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, wchar-t

I'm trying to convert a vector<wchar_t> to string (and then print it).

```
std::string(vector_.begin(), vector_.end());
```

This code works fine, except äöü ÄÖÜ ß.
They will be converted to:

```
���
```

I also tried converting to wstring and printing with wcout, but I got the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use wstring instead. Or you need to encode it from unicode to ANSI.

Comment: As I said, I tried wstring, it has the same output

Comment: Is your terminal set to the appropriate character encoding?

Comment: yes have the right encoding

Comment: @LiamK. What is that encoding? You cannot magically convert one encoding to another (at least not in C++).

Comment: vscode - UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @LiamK. Put another way, since you are using `wchar_t` your source encoding is presumably UTF-16 or UTF-32. What the encoding you expect to have when you have copied the characters to a `std::string`? Whatever that is, you have to do the work to make that conversion happen.

Comment: @LiamK. OK then you need to write a UTF-?? to UTF-8 conversion, or find some third party code to do that for you. Historically C++ has not been very good with Unicode (since it predates the widespread adoption of it). Depending on compiler and version you might be able to use `std::code_cvt` or you might use a third party library or you might write the conversion yourself.

Comment: I want to print the string using cout.. I googled and it seems like cout uses utf-8

Comment: @LiamK. There is absolutely no guarantee that cout uses UTF-8. It might, it might not, it might depend on how your console/terminal is set up

Comment: @LiamK. `cout` doesn't use any particular encoding. It is totally unaware of encodings and only outputs the `char`s you give it. It's your responsibility to handle encodings.

Comment: cout just passes the bytes you give it to the terminal so `cout` doesn't use utf-8 but your terminal might (unless you're on Windows)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I figured it out.
The converted string is UTF-16 and I needed UTF-8.

Comment: @Liam: If you got a minute, could you post your solution as an answer ? This might be of interest to others in the future. String encodings are a notorious beast.

Comment: What you should use is `std::wstring` instead, since you deal with `wchar_t` instead of `char`. It may not necessarily solve your display issue but at least, you won't slice your `wchar_t` values anymore (because `wchar_t` is bigger than `char`). `std::wcout` may help as well

Comment: Yeah I will post, just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution:**

First I convert my `vector<wchar_t>` to an `utf16string` like this:

```
std::u16string(buffer_.begin(), buffer_.end());
```

Then I use this function, I found somewhere on here:

```
std::string IO::Interface::UTF16_To_UTF8(std::u16string const& str) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t, 0x10ffff,
        std::codecvt_mode::little_endian>, char16_t> cnv;
    std::string utf8 = cnv.to_bytes(str);
    if(cnv.converted() < str.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("incomplete conversion");
    return utf8;
}
```

I did not write the conversion function, but it works just as expected.
With this I can successfully convert a `vector<wchar_t>` to `string`